# Alternative word for "valued at"

Tags: word-request

In the below excerpt of an essay, what would be the most appropriate alternative word for **valued at**.

> I hurriedly scanned the next question **valued at** 200 points.

Here, **valued at** means "estimated" usually used with money. I wish to convey a more positive meaning with a little exclamation attached to it.

I wish to convey the meaning:

> I hurriedly scanned the next question **valued at 200 points!**.

The exclamation mark doesn't convey this emphasis properly since someone may think I meant to emphasize "hurriedly".

Comment: This question appears to request "proofreading", which is [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on ELL. Also, if you ask for a word or phrase ("word-request"), then please keep it to one request per post. Lastly, it seems you can use a thesaurus to find alternatives for "check it out" using "search", "peek", or possibly "check it out". I would consider "worth" instead of "valued for".

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj It still isn't clear exactly what you are asking. If it is "How do I assign the exclamation point to 200 points and not to _hurriedly_?" then the answer is: Write two separate sentences, or use the semicolon. Thus: _**I hurriedly scanned the next question; it was valued at 200 points!**_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about questions on an exam, I think the term most generally used is *worth*:

> I hurriedly scanned the next question; it was worth 200 points!

I agree with the comment left earlier; this looks like an ideal place for a semi-colon. Not only is that the best way to punctuate what you are writing, but it also eliminates your concern about the reader mistakenly thinking that the exclamation point is emphasizing *hurriedly*.

If you want to emphasize how many points this question is worth, you could also use a modifier. The one that comes to my mind is *whopping*:

> I hurriedly scanned the next question; it was worth a whopping 200 points!

That's an informal term used to denote a very large quantity of something.

Comment: Would this sentence be simple enough?: I hurriedly scanned the next question worth a whopping 200 points. What I meant to do was not use the exclamation point altogether.

Comment: I still think it reads better with a semi-colon. Or, if you don't like that, you could use a dash: _I hurriedly scanned the next question – worth a whopping 200 points._

Comment: You should also not accept my answer right away. There may be other, better answers coming. See [not so fast](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) on meta.

Comment: This was the first answer did not make use of the exclamation so I got excited

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj It is very gratifying to everyone who answers questions here to see you say that you got _excited_ about receiving a good answer. It's wonderful to know that you care about learning as much as we care about helping you learn.